# LinAlgError: SVD did not converge when trying to use Arima

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels, arima

I try to run this simple code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

data = np.array([347, 347, 347, 347, 347, 347, 347, 347, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, \
 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, \
 345, 345, 344, 314])

model = ARIMA(data, order=(2,1,0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
output = model_fit.forecast()
yhat = output[0]

yhat
```

but it displays this error:

> LinAlgError: SVD did not converge

( Backtrace from `model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)` )

**Note:** If I remove the last cell in the data ( `314` ) it works just fine.

I wonder why it happens, as what I'm doing is loop every 30 rows in my dataset and try to predict the value with ARIMA, and in this iteration it just stopped displays errors.